# Javascript array of dates - not iterating properly (jquery ui datepicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, arrays, datepicker

I have some code which builds an array of date ranges. I then call a function (from the jquery UI datepicker), passing it a date, and compare that date with dates in the array. I'm doing it this way because the dates are stored in a cms and this is the only way I can output them.

Unfortunately my code only checks the first date range in the array - and I can't figure out why! I think it's probably something simple (/stupid!) - if anyone can shed some light on it I'd be extremely grateful!

The code is below - the june-september range (ps1-pe1) works fine, the december to jan is totally ignored...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 

var ps1 = new Date(2010, 06-1, 18); // range1 start
var pe1 = new Date(2010, 09-1, 03); // range1 end
var ps2 = new Date(2010, 12-1, 20); // range2 start
var pe2 = new Date(2011, 01-1, 02); // range2 end

var peakStart = new Array(ps1,ps2);
var peakEnd = new Array(pe1,pe2);
function checkDay(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    for (var i=0; i<peakStart.length; i++) {
        if ((date > peakStart[i]) && (date < peakEnd[i])) {
            return [(day == 5), ''];
        } else {
            return [(day == 1 || day == 5), ''];
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yaggo is quite right, but apparently too terse.

You want to move the second return statement outside of the loop.

```
function checkDay(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    for (var i=0; i<peakStart.length; i++) {
        if ((date > peakStart[i]) && (date < peakEnd[i])) {
            return [(day == 5), ''];
        }
    }
    // it's not during a peak period
    return [(day == 1 || day == 5), ''];
}
```

Comment: Many thanks brainjam and Yaggo! This solution worked and also showed me that I should take a break once in a while as now it's obvious :) Thanks again guys

Answer (score 2):

You always call return in the first iteration of for loop.

Comment: Sorry Yaggo, I don't quite understand - should I write a variable inside the loop and then return it outside?

Comment: OK, I've also tried this (modified function, other vars/arrays remain), which makes the second range work and ignores the first!

    function checkDay(date, season) {
     var day = date.getDay();
     var period = "";
     for (var i=0; i<peakStart.length; i++) {
      if ((date > peakStart[i]) && (date < peakEnd[i])) {
       period = "peak";
      } else {
       period = "non_peak";
      }
     }
     if (period=="peak") { return [(day == 5), ''] } else { return [(day == 1 || day == 5), '']};
    }

Comment: In the modified function, the second iteration of the loop clobbers whatever value went into 'period' during the first iteration.  Which is why it apparently ignores the first range.